# How to write list of strings to csv or xlsx file

Tags: python, csv, text, output

I have a list of lists;

```
L = 
[
['Route', 1, (20, 21), (22, 23),...]
["Path", 2,  (20, 21), (25, 26),...]
]
```

And ideally I'd like to put this data into a file, foo.csv or bar.xslx, such that

- The string is the first element in a row, A1
- The number is the 2nd, A2
- And then the next n elements are the **pairs** of the numbers.

Each time I've tried to do this myself it ends up splitting the items by the comma in the pairs.

Comment: Have you tried using the "csv" module of the standard library?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question depends on what you mean be this:

> next n elements are the pairs of the numbers

If you want items like `(20, 21)` to show up in your .csv file, that is impossible since it contains a comma.

If you can't change the comma delimiter, you'll need to choose another file format. For example, you can generate a Tab Separated Values (.tsv) using the following code:

```
L = [
    ['Route', 1, (20, 21), (22, 23)],
    ["Path", 2,  (20, 21), (25, 26)],
]

with open('out.tsv', 'w') as file:
    for row in L:
        file.write('\t'.join(map(str, row)) + '\n')
```

Running this code producing the following `out.tsv` file:

```
Route   1   (20, 21)    (22, 23)
Path    2   (20, 21)    (25, 26)
```

Comment: I knew that commas might not work but that's why I specified maybe xlsx. Is there a way to have it transposed so that the information is on a horizontal?
Route 1 (20, 21), ...

Comment: I edited the answer above to make the file laid out horizontally. Is this more of what you are looking for?

Unfortunately .xlsx files are binary so you can't easily construct them with  `.write` statements. Maybe you could look into xlsxwriter: https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/

Answer (score 0):

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(L)

df.to_csv("out.csv")

Answer (score 0):

If you want csv, you will have to put each tuple in quotes.  If your application can deal with the second value as a string you can use:

```
with open('out.csv','wt') as f:
    for row in L:
       print (*list(map(lambda x:str(x).join('"'*2),row)),sep=',',file=f)
```

Apologies for the one-liner in the print statement, but figuring out what it does will be a lesson in itself.